# Solving of an integral

Tags: integration

$$\int \left(\frac{x^2 + \arctan(x)}{1 + x^2}\right) dx$$

Could anyone help me calculate this integral? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Break the integral in two :

$$ \int \frac{ x^2 }{x^2 + 1} dx + \int  \frac{ \arctan x }{1 + x^2} dx $$

To solve the second one : Notice $d( \arctan x ) = \frac{ dx}{1 + x^2} $ So

$$ \int \frac{ \arctan x }{1 + x^2} dx = \int \arctan x\, d(\arctan x ) = (\arctan x)^2/2 + K$$

As for the first integral, notice

$$ \int \frac{ x^2}{1 + x^2} = \int \frac{ x^2 + 1 - 1 }{1+x^2} dx = \int dx - \int \frac{ 1}{1 + x^2 } dx = x - \arctan x  $$

Comment: nice, :) +1, good answer

Comment: For $\arctan x$  you can use \arctan x in $\LaTeX$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have one question, I don't understand how you solved the second one? Can you explain in depth how it's done?

Comment: the trick is adding one and substracting one. IT is a trick.

Comment: I meant the second part, not the first one.

Comment: I am using substitutiong $t = \arctan x $

Comment: I understand. And where does the /2 comes from? And what is K? Is it a constant? Thank you.

Comment: when using power rule $\int t^n = \frac{ t^{n+1}}{n+1} $

Comment: Thanks a lot, learned a lot from this answer :)

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:
$$\int \left(\frac{x^2 + \arctan(x)}{1 + x^2}\right) dx=\int \left(x^2 + \arctan(x)\right) d(\arctan x)=\\
\left(x^2 + \arctan(x)\right)\arctan x-\int \arctan xd(x^2 + \arctan(x))=\\
\left(x^2 + \arctan(x)\right)\arctan x-\int \arctan xd(x^2)-\int \arctan xd(\arctan(x))=\\
\left(x^2 + \arctan(x)\right)\arctan x-\dfrac{(\arctan x)^2}{2}-\int \arctan xd(x^2)$$

$$\text{Now, }\int \arctan xd(x^2)=x^2\arctan x-\int \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx$$

$$\text{This gives }\dfrac{(\arctan x)^2}{2}+\int \dfrac{x^2+1-1}{x^2+1}dx=\dfrac{(\arctan x)^2}{2}+x-\arctan x+C\\
\implies \int \left(\frac{x^2 + \arctan(x)}{1 + x^2}\right) dx=\dfrac{(\arctan x)^2}{2}+x-\arctan x+C$$